# Next ios sdk version might not have the complete(/any) google map implementation. Is using google map logic a smart option for ios dev now?

Tags: ios, google-maps

Just in case Apple brings its own implementation of some form of Map Logic as reported by techcrunch here : http://techcrunch.com/2012/05/11/come-ios-6-apple-will-reportedly-kiss-google-maps-goodbye/

Is it smart to implement any logic in ios that is dependent on Google Maps? Specially when you are still in that dev phase where you can choose?

I simply need to know the country of a user without involving sim(should run on iPod) so do I have a safer option apart from using google's reverse geocode for future ios compatibility just in case?

Comment: Unless you can see into the future, or work for apple's maps team, I seriously doubt there is an answer to this question.  It would be easy for them to simply change the logic behind each class, but keep the same methods and classes, but it would be just as easy to start from the ground up.